# Plug-in org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter was unable to load class org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.HeadlessTestApplication

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter was unable to load class org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.HeadlessTestApplication.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:920)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/IPlatformRunnable
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:196)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPlatformRunnable cannot be found by org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter_2.0.0
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

Does org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:2.0.0:test support jdk 11 and Eclipse 4.23?

Comment: The IPlatformRunnable class was removed in 4.20 see [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564890) That bug reports says that the tycho plug-in was updated in a newer version.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449, updated my Tycho version and issue got resolved.